# Homemade Cat6 ethernet not working when PoE is in use

Tags: ethernet, gigabit-ethernet, cat6, rj-45, power-over-ethernet

I've just crimped together a couple of CAT6 Ethernet cables. The cables are about 20 meters long each. They are shielded and so are the connectors. They run along each other from one room to the switch.

The cables work just fine as long at PoE is not in use. When PoE is in use the cables deliver the right amount of power to the device, but network traffic dies.

That means that either download or upload (depending on perspective) is working around the expected 1 Gbps when tested with a Raspberry Pi 4 and iperf3.

Traffic in the opposite direction slows to a crawl meaning kilo bits per second making the connection unusable. That happens when both cables are connected and also when just a single cable is in use.

The PoE-ports on the switch work with other cables made by me. The cables I've used for testing haven't been as long as the two problematic cables though.

I have rolled back the cables wire mesh shielding at the connectors, so it touches the connectors metal sheet. I'm not sure if that is necessary or if that is the way to do it at all.

And again when the cables are not delivering PoE everything works as expected. Around 1 Gbps both ways.

Anybody has any idea what might be the cause of the problem and maybe how to fix it?

PS I'm not using PoE-injectors but the power from the 60W switch, which has no problem powering devices in general.

I have tried a cable tester as the first thing. Everything checks out. Including ground connection.

Comment: So what exactly is your question?  [Sounds like a cable fault](https://usercontent1.hubstatic.com/5690696_f520.jpg)

Comment: Sry, the question is if anybody has any thoughts on what might be the issue. Regarding cable faults, it would have to be the exact same cable fault on two different cables. Both of which otherwise work fine on gigabit speed when no PoE. I was wondering whether maybe PoE could generate some interference under certain conditions. Apart from that I'm pretty much at a loss as to what might be wrong.

Comment: Crimp yourself a short cable and test. If it works, something is wrong with your long cables. If it doesn't work, get a short cable from somewhere else and test. If that doesn't work, it's your PoE equipment. (Debugging works by "asking questions" in the form of tests, taking out parts of the whole, until you've nailed down which part is faulty. It doesn't work by asking people on the Internet to use a crystal ball to predict what's wrong).

Comment: I have crimped myself a shorter cable - as stated in the original post. Hence the 'The PoE-ports on the switch work with other homemade cables.' And I have searched - a lot - on the internet for a similar problem, and come up empty handed. Nothing about cables working fine, except when PoE is going through them. I'm not asking people to use a crystal ball. My hope is, that maybe the above situation rings a bell somewhere.

Comment: You made no mention those cables were made by you.  Have you tried a cable tester?  Have you tried a connectivity test between the applicable wires in the screenshot?

Comment: Yes. I have tried a cable tester as the first thing. Everything checks out. Including ground connection. And you are right, it isn't clear that the test cables were also made by me. I will put the info in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Likely, you've got split pairs. Without PoE, the cable barely works (check the error counters after full load) and with PoE it tips over the edge.

Double check that the sequence you've crimped *exactly* matches the twisted pairs in the cable. The pairs are 1-2, 3-6, 4-5, 7-8. If you can't make out the pairs any more, remove some more insulation.

[image]
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI/TIA-568#Wiring

A simple cable tester does *not* test proper pairing, just shorts and continuity.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this poe problem for my crimp method, in my case, I have to crimp 70% instead of full strength for the rj45, I mean if I crimp fully to the end, the poe not working, but If I crimp like 70%, then the poe with this new rj45 works perfectly, I believe the copper pins is not contacted tightly enough for the electric power, so I crimp less and leave the pin bit higher instead lower,then the rj45 socket pin can contact tightly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).